# How to implement custom search on the server database in Android 2.3?

Tags: java, android, search, searchview

I have to implement custom search in my application for android 2.3.I have some `EditText` in which user type one letter and then I send response to the server, retrieve all the results matches this one letter and then I need to display them in a list. When user types second button I also need to send new response and refresh data and so on.

The question how can I do this in Android 2.3?  What should i use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be too open ended with too many questions to give a really helpful answer.

What you use in your app will heavily depend on how the server's API is expecting you to communicate.  I, for one, am all for hiding the specifics of what a server does from the application and put all the "smarts" behind the API.  So a query like:

```
http:/blah.com/getresults?search=a
```

would result in whatever matches 'a'.  If it is searching a MySql Db, processing a Google search, or accessing files on the system doesn't matter.

Your code needs to worry about the interface to the API to make queries and processing the results, whether they're free formatted text, JSON objects, or whatever.

Maybe rewording your question or provide information on what you know would help.